# Java if I have an array of javax.servlet.http.Part, will one part always represent one file

Tags: java

I have an array of `javax.servlet.http.Part` which I get because the user sends multiple files to the server. Now based on the limited testing I've done till now I see that all files sent only have one respective part as opposed to one file having many parts. Can this always be the case? The user is sending data in form-data.
Can I safely just assume this and move forward or there is some max size to each part beyond which it'll subdivide the file into multiple parts?

Comment: Why would you be keeping `Part`s in an array? Sounds memory-intensive (potentially)…

Comment: @g00se It is a web-app to be used by internal team so that concern is rather limited at the moment.

Comment: Each file will be in one `Part` normally, perhaps always